# textBox refocus if input invalid

Tags: c#, silverlight, validation, focus

I am a slow learner when it comes to programming, sorry.  I am doing a windows phone application in silverlight.  I am trying to validate input.

The problem I have is that I am detecting the bad input and the message comes up, but the keyboard dissappears, effectively allowing them to go on with the input error still there.  So is there a way to stop them from leaving without having valid input?

Thankyou

```
bool IsDigitsOnly(string str) {
        foreach (char c in str) {
            if (c < '0' || c > '9') {

                return false;

            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    protected Boolean noLetters() {



        if (!IsDigitsOnly(ReadySecTxtBox.Text)) {
            MessageBox.Show("digits only");
            ReadySecTxtBox.Focus();
            return false;
        }
        if (!IsDigitsOnly(RoundSecTxtBox.Text)) {
            MessageBox.Show("digits only");
            return false;
        }
        if (!IsDigitsOnly(RestSecTxtBox.Text)) {
            MessageBox.Show("digits only");
            return false;
        }
        if (!IsDigitsOnly(RelaxSecTxtBox.Text)) {
            MessageBox.Show("digits only");
            return false;
        }
        if (!IsDigitsOnly(ReadyMinTxtBox.Text)) {
            MessageBox.Show("digits only");
            return false;
        }
        if (!IsDigitsOnly(RoundMinTxtBox.Text)) {
            MessageBox.Show("digits only");
            return false;
        }
        if (!IsDigitsOnly(RestMinTxtBox.Text)) {
            MessageBox.Show("digits only");
            return false;
        }
        if (!IsDigitsOnly(RelaxMinTxtBox.Text)) {
            MessageBox.Show("digits only");
            return false;
        }
        if (!IsDigitsOnly(NoRoundsTxtBox.Text)) {
            MessageBox.Show("digits only");
            return false;
        }
        else return true;

    }

    protected Boolean validInputs(){


        if (noLetters()) {


            if (int.Parse(ReadySecTxtBox.Text) < 0 || int.Parse(ReadySecTxtBox.Text) > 59) {
                MessageBox.Show("seconds must be between 0 and 59");

                return false;
            }
            if (int.Parse(RoundSecTxtBox.Text) < 0 || int.Parse(RoundSecTxtBox.Text) > 59) {
                MessageBox.Show("seconds must be between 0 and 59");
                return false;
            }
            if (int.Parse(RestSecTxtBox.Text) < 0 || int.Parse(RestSecTxtBox.Text) > 59) {
                MessageBox.Show("seconds must be between 0 and 59");
                return false;
            }
            if (int.Parse(RelaxSecTxtBox.Text) < 0 || int.Parse(RelaxSecTxtBox.Text) > 59) {
                MessageBox.Show("seconds must be between 0 and 59");
                return false;
            }

            if (int.Parse(ReadyMinTxtBox.Text) < 0 || int.Parse(ReadyMinTxtBox.Text) > 99) {
                MessageBox.Show("minutes must be between 0 and 99");
                return false;
            }
            if (int.Parse(RoundMinTxtBox.Text) < 0 || int.Parse(RoundMinTxtBox.Text) > 99) {
                MessageBox.Show("minutes must be between 0 and 99");
                return false;
            }
            if (int.Parse(RestMinTxtBox.Text) < 0 || int.Parse(RestMinTxtBox.Text) > 99) {
                MessageBox.Show("minutes must be between 0 and 99");
                return false;
            }
            if (int.Parse(RelaxMinTxtBox.Text) < 0 || int.Parse(RelaxMinTxtBox.Text) > 99) {
                MessageBox.Show("minutes must be between 0 and 99");
                return false;
            }

            if (int.Parse(NoRoundsTxtBox.Text) < 1 || int.Parse(NoRoundsTxtBox.Text) > 99) {
                MessageBox.Show("number of rounds must be between 1 and 99");
                return false;
            }


            else return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }

    protected override void OnManipulationStarted(ManipulationStartedEventArgs e) {

        if (validInputs()) {


            totalSec = (int.Parse(RoundSecTxtBox.Text) + int.Parse(RestSecTxtBox.Text)) * int.Parse(NoRoundsTxtBox.Text)
                + int.Parse(RelaxSecTxtBox.Text) + int.Parse(ReadySecTxtBox.Text);
            totalMin = (int.Parse(RoundMinTxtBox.Text) + int.Parse(RestMinTxtBox.Text)) * int.Parse(NoRoundsTxtBox.Text)
                + int.Parse(RelaxMinTxtBox.Text) + int.Parse(ReadyMinTxtBox.Text);

            TotalMinTxtBox.Text = totalMin.ToString("00");
            TotalSecTxtBox.Text = totalSec.ToString("00");
        }

        base.OnManipulationStarted(e);


    }
```

Comment: have you tried putting focus back to the Textbox after you show your messagebox?

Comment: when are you detecting the bad input? on button click? Please provide more details, maybe all you need is to set e.Cancel = true; TextBox.Focus()

Comment: yes I have tried to put focus on textBox.  Another thing I have noticed is that when I hit return key on windows phone it doesn't do anything.  On an android app it is normal for return to enter the input (my only experience is with using an andoid phone).  So to register input, currently I have to click off keyboard.  So maybe it is losing focus because I am tapping somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

Use this piece of code snippet:

```
private bool Validate(string text)
{
    if (!IsDigitsOnly(text)) {
        MessageBox.Show("digits only");            
        return false;
    }
}

protected Boolean noLetters() {

    if (!Validate(ReadySecTxtBox.Text))
    {
        ReadySecTxtBox.Focus();
        return false;
    }

    if (!Validate(RoundSecTxtBox.Text))
    {
        RoundSecTxtBox.Focus();
        return false;
    }

    //...

    else return true;
}
```

**ADDED:** Or you can do it this way.

```
private bool ValidateAndFocus(ref TextBox txt)
{
    if (!IsDigitsOnly(txt.Text)) {
        MessageBox.Show("digits only");            
        txt.Focus();
        return false;
    }
}

protected Boolean noLetters() {

    if (!ValidateAndFocus(ref ReadySecTxtBox))
        return false;

    if (!ValidateAndFocus(ref RoundSecTxtBox))
        return false;

    //...

    else return true;
}
```

Comment: I don't think its a good practice to put the unrelated code in any method.. in your case  `txt.Focus();` in `Validate` method.. you cannot reuse that code if you write like this.. a method should do just what its definition says.. put it in `noLetters` method after validation fails..